# How to make sure that a certain Port is not occupied by any other process

Tags: windows, networking

I am working on a Java EE Application in a Windows environment. (I am using Windows 7)

I am using Tomcat Server, unfortunately port number 8080 is busy (used by Oracle). Now I want to assign a different port to Tomcat.

So before changing inside conf/server.xml file, I want to make sure that a certain port is not occupied by any other process and it's free.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use "netstat" to check whether a port is available or not.

Use the `netstat -anp | find "port number"` command to find whether a port is occupied by an another process or not. If it is occupied by an another process, it will show the process id of that process.

**You have to put : before port number to get the actual output**

Ex
`netstat -anp | find ":8080"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer , as said i executed the following command on Windows Command Prompt C:\Users\kiran>netstat -anp | find 8086           It showed 
FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: You should cover the port number with in quotes. For example, netstat -ano | find "8086"

Comment: Aravind , after issuing that command C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.33\bin>netstat -anp | find "8080"

Nothing came . Thank you .

Comment: I copy pasted the command and executed the same under Command Prompt , it displayed nothing .

Comment: Means no process occupied that port number. If u are not sure, try the TCP viewer from SysInternals and check whether the port is listed in it or not.

Comment: Try this one in windows:        netstat -ano | find "7"

Comment: not working in windows 10. "netstat -ano|findstr port no" is working fine

Comment: -an works but -anp does not work. FYI I am using win 10 Pro 64 bit

Comment: I am trying to check if the exact port is in free or not. I used `netstat -an | find ":566"`. It is returning info that the port 56687 is in use. I tried with `an`,`ano`, `find` and `findstr`. I used `:` before the port number. But all returning the same results. OS am trying is Windows 10.

Comment: I tried all modifications like find/findstr/-an/-ano/:9200/9200 but non of them give a result. It silently ends up. Max I get an error "wrong parameter" if port number is not enclosed in ""

Comment: for windows 10 netstat -ano|find ":port_no" , below answer is working

Comment: shoud use **command prompt**, not **PowerShell**

Answer (score 54):

It's `netstat -ano|findstr port no`

Result would show process id in last column

Comment: `netstat -ano|findstr 3306`  Nothing happened when i run this command

Comment: @sam
Based on answers
`netstat -ano | find ":3306" `

Comment: @MostafaFallah answer worked for me. Anyone, remember to try other ports so you better see how the command works.

Comment: Better answer in my opinion because it also works in PowerShell. Accepted answer is **only for CMD**

Comment: downvoted because you used an unnecessary acronym, there's no "o" in number

Answer (score 21):

`netstat -ano|find ":port_no"` will give you the list.
a: Displays all connections and listening ports.
      n: Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
      o: Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection .

example : `netstat -ano | find ":1900"`
  This gives you the result like this.

```
UDP    107.109.121.196:1900   *:*                                    1324  
UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                                    1324  
UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                                    1324  
UDP    [fe80::8db8:d9cc:12a8:2262%13]:1900  *:*                      1324
```

Comment: `> nestat -ano | find ":443"` gives 
`netstat: illegal option -- o`

Comment: This is the command that worked on Windows 7-64. Tested with XAMPP Apache server down, nothing came up on port 80. With same up, port 80 displayed an entry, as expected.

Answer (score 10):

If you prefer Powershell, use this. You will get the name of the process.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 9093).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   6021    1464  2760976    2131548     290.39  25512   2 java
```

The PID is in `Id` column, and it provides process name, as well.

If no process is using this port, you get a red error message.

If you want to kill the process with PID 25512, use

```
taskkill /PID 25512 /F
```

`/F` means force, some processes cannot be killed without `/F`

Answer (score 2):

It's (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort "port no.").OwningProcess

Comment: its show this error
Get-NetTCPConnection : No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '55283'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort "55283").OwningProcess
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (55283:UInt16) [Get-NetTCPConnection], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_LocalPort,Get-NetTCPConnection

Answer (score 1):

If this is a purely local concern e.g. you want to run tomcat locally to test the application you're working on, something which often works is to configure port `0`. In that case when the application port-binds it will be allocated a random "ephemeral" port by the OS, which hopefully it logs out.

You'll have to check if that's supported by tomcat, but I would expect it is given [past answers mentioning it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158683/8182118).

It avoids having to hardcode ports and issues of [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), though it is obviously somewhat less convenient as you need to get the port you need to connect to every time.

The alternative is to just try out a bunch of free ports e.g. 8000[0] and 8888 are common alternate ports for HTTP servers. 8008 is also an official IANA alternate port though I can't remember ever seing it used.

[0] though officially assigned to iRDMI

Answer (score 1):

If someone is trying in **windows 10 pro**, netstat **-anp** might not list any connection, so try **netstat -an** and add **| find** to find your desire port

for example I want to check in port 65432 is being currently used then I do

```
netstat -an|find "65432"
```

Answer (score 0):

netstat -ano| grep

this will give status of the port if being used or not