# Error: 26-Error Locating Server/Instance Specified, working from one client but not from another

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I know there are 100's of article on this issue however in my case. I am able to connect to same instance of sql server from one machine on internet while not able to connect from another machine on internet using same credentials.

I am using SQL authentication.

TCP port are enabled, sqlbrowser service is running. Appropriate ports are added to firewall. All of these settings are checked on machine where SQL Server instance is hosted.

On Client
Firewall is off, sqlbrowser service is running.

Comment: so your sql server TCP port is open and accessible from all IPs? is there any black or white listing in your firewall?

Comment: There are no such rules of blacklisting IP addresses. All IP address are invited until they have valid credentials.

Comment: Did a telnet work on that TCP port from the second client?

Comment: I don't know how to use telnet. I have to take a look into this. However I checked PING command and I am getting a reply from server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot connect to SQL Server named instance from another SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029073/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-named-instance-from-another-sql-server)

Comment: For me, issue was with DNS. As soon as I changed my internet provider. Created mobile hotspot everything worked smoothly.