# While installing Jenkins says C:\Users\Dell\.jenkins\war\images\RRZEIconSet-License.url (Access is denied)java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to install Jenkins while installing its return below results, I am struggling to install the Jenkins. This is a showstopper for me to learn selenium.

[image]

Analysis from my end:

1. As Jenkins supports the JDK (8,11) version. I have installed JDK with version 11.
2. Declared in the environment variables(bin) and JAVA_HOME variable
3. Checked the java version through command prompt `java -version` and `javac -version`. looks fine with the proper version i.e 11.
4. Downloaded the Jenkins in the [official website](https://www.jenkins.io/download/) Generic Java Package(.war)
5. Trying using this command to install `C:\Jenkins>java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090` gives me the below error.

   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Dell.jenkins\war\images\RRZEIconSet-License.url (Access is denied)

Before I posted, I have checked the related posts but the error was related to the Java error code issue. But I am installing for Jenkins, I haven't found any answers related to the Jenkins. Hence, I am posting this issue

Comment: Oops Apologies. Not sure, how I have missed it. I have attached. Can you please take a look at the error of the image?

Comment: I have followed the same process of yours and worked fine for me. Here is the line from the cmd prompt.  
{Jenkins v2.263.2,/,file:///C:/Users/XX.XXX/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\XX.XXX\.jenkins\war}

Additionally, de-complied the same war file and found the "RRZEIconSet-License.url" file as well. 

Only problem, I can now think of is your Access issue i.e. they way you login into your machine or Port is already used by some other service.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your validation. Shall I use a different port? What all port we can use, can you list it out here please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817500/how-to-make-sure-that-a-certain-port-is-not-occupied-by-any-other-process#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20%22netstat%22%20to,process%20id%20of%20that%20process.

Comment: Re-read your question, why don't you just install Jenkins through .msi installer, this is also working fine for me.                                 https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/windows/

Comment: Thanks, Atul for your support:) I appreciate it, giving some time of your and share your thoughts on this. Finally, I have installed Jenkins.

Comment: As I was new to this, I was following up with the trainer guidelines. I didn't have any clue about this.  I was literally suffering a lot to install in all the aspects. One word, Thanks.

Comment: I would say-Post your answer in your question, how you solved it,so that it will help others.

Comment: Sure, I have followed the same procedure as the link shared by you.